# How can I share a folder of content between multiple ASP.Net projects in studio?

Tags: asp.net, resources, sharing

I would like to share 2 folders of content ('stylesheets' and 'graphics') between multiple asp.net projects in a solution.

Is there a way to do this and have studio display the graphics and such appropriately at design time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked into this deeply a while back and found no great solution right there in Visual Studio.NET.  What I ended up doing was using my source control system to share the folders.

I used Subversion Externals to share to multiple working copies, from a single source in Subversion.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s04.html

I know there's a similar sharing concept in Source Safe and likely other source control systems as well.

Comment: A similar link (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.externals.html) to the latest version(1.5) of svnbook suggests that externals now supports relative pathing...

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, but I believe if you make it a virtual folder in IIS for both websites, it will appear properly in VS  (Of course, this means using IIS instead of the internal VS webserver).